# why is this code bad?

Tags: c#

Below is a code in C# for rss reader, why this code is bad? this class generates a list of the 5 most recent posts, sorted by title. What do you use to analyze code in C#?

```
    static Story[] Parse(string content)
    {
        var items = new List<string>();
        int start = 0;
        while (true)
        {

            var nextItemStart = content.IndexOf("<item>", start);
            var nextItemEnd = content.IndexOf("</item>", nextItemStart);
            if (nextItemStart < 0 || nextItemEnd < 0) break;

            String nextItem = content.Substring(nextItemStart, nextItemEnd + 7 - nextItemStart);
            items.Add(nextItem);
            start = nextItemEnd;
        }

        var stories = new List<Story>();
        for (byte i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            stories.Add(new Story()
            {
                title = Regex.Match(items[i], "(?<=<title>).*(?=</title>)").Value,
                link = Regex.Match(items[i], "(?<=<link>).*(?=</link>)").Value,
                date = Regex.Match(items[i], "(?<=<pubDate>).*(?=</pubdate>)").Value
            });
        }

        return stories.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please describe what you mean by "bad"? Although I can say one thing; why not use LINQ to XML to parse this?

Comment: bad means a garbage code or has stylistic, functionality, maintainability problems.

Comment: Something can not really be good or bad without a metric of some sort. This code could be done in several ways but without understanding what you are trying to maximize it's hard to understand what to improve.

Comment: what is the disadvantage of using code like this and not the XmlReader or LINQ to Xml?

Comment: For the question on what to use to analyze C# code, I would recommend (1) your experience and (2) your intellect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - there are already plenty of answers why one should not be using Regex to parse HTML/XHTML/XML...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bad because it's using string parsing when there are [excellent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) in the framework for parsing XML. Even better, there are [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) to deal with RSS feeds.

**ETA:**

Sorry to not have answered your second question earlier. There are a great number of tools to analyze correctness and quality of C# code. There's probably a huge list compiled somewhere, but here's a few I use on a daily basis to help ensure quality code:

- [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (code formatting standards)
- [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (idiomatic programming, gotcha catching)
- [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx) (code correctness, standards adherence, idiomatic programming)
- [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) (white box testing)
- [Nitriq](http://www.nitriq.com/) (code quality metrics)
- [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) (unit testing)

Answer (score 4):

why don't use XmlReader or XmlDocument or LINQ to Xml?

Comment: +1 - exactly - parsers we're designed for problems it looks like that code is trying to address.  Also, doing RegEx matches inside a order n byte loop may be expensive.  Having magic number like 7 that happens to align with a string constant further up in the code etc...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't parse XML with string functions and regular expressions. XML can get very complicated and be formatted many ways that a real XML parser like XmlReader can handle, but will break your simple string parsing code.

Basically: don't try and reinvent the wheel (an xml parser), especially when you don't realize how complicated that wheel actually is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the worst thing for the code is the performance issue. You should parse the xml string into a XDocument(or similar structure) instead of parse it again and again using regex.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it uses `byte` as a indexer instead of `int` (what if `items` has more items in it than a `byte` can represent?). It doesn't use idiomatic C# (see user1645569's response). It also unnecessarily uses `var` instead of specific data types (that's more stylistic though, but for me I prefer not to, hence by my metric it's not ideal (and you've given no other metric)).

Let me clarify what I am saying about "unnecessarily using `var`": `var` in and of itself is not bad, and I am not suggesting that. I am (mostly) suggesting the usage here isn't very consistent. For example, explicitly declaring `start` as an `int`, but then declaring `nextItemEnd` as `var` (which will deduce to `int`) and assigning `nextItemEnd` to `start` seems (to me) like a weird mixture between wanting to automatically deduce a variable's type and explicitly declaring it. I think it's good that `var` was not used in `start`'s declaration (because then it's not exactly clear if the intent is an integer or a floating point number), but I (personally) don't think it helps any to declare `nextItemStart` and `nextItemEnd` as `var`. I tend to prefer to use `var` for more complex/longer data types (similar to how I use `auto` in C++ for iterators, but not for "simpler" data types).

Comment: Explanation for the -1, please?

Comment: I haven't down voted, but using var for local variables is recommended

Comment: @sleimanjneidi: Thanks, perhaps that's why. I'll clarify to say that `var` in and of itself isn't bad. I've got nothing against `var`; I just don't think it was used great here (if he declares `start` as `int`, and then `nextItemEnd` as `var`, and then assigns `nextItemEnd` to `start`, I would personally prefer him to be consistent with explicitly declaring types instead of switching between `int` and `var`).

Answer (score 1):

simply because you are reinventing a `xml parser` , use `Linq to xml` instead, it is very simple and clean.I am sure that you can do all the above in three lines of code if you use `Linq to XML` , your code uses a lot of magic numbers (ex: 7-n ..), the thing that make it unstable and non generic